# Android: Set menu visibility within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-menu

I have an android app that has a side menu and the main body of content is inside a fragment. So far there are 3 fragments (Home, Settings, Help).  What I am trying to do is have the menu in the top right only appear in the home fragments. 
Using

```
this.setHasOptionsMenu(false);
```

doesn't do anything so I am obviously using that wrong. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
menu.findItem(R.id.MENU_ITEM).setVisible(false);
```

For all of your menu items in the method `onPrepareOptionsMenu(...)`. You should end up with something similar to this:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.MENU_ITEM_ONE).setVisible(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.MENU_ITEM_TWO).setVisible(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.MENU_ITEM_THREE).setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late reply but this worked thank you.